# How can I show that and $n\times{n}$ matrix of the form in the description has a determinant of zero for $n>2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition

In General,  $n>2$, $a_{i,j}=a_{i,j-1}+1$ and the matrix will be of the following form:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&...&n\\n+1&n+2&n+3&...&n+n\\2n+1&2n+2&2n+3&...&2n+n\\...&...&...&...&...\\(n-1)n+1&(n-1)n+2&(n-1)n+3&...&n^2\end{bmatrix}_{n \times {n}}$

I tried to show this by row operations, and I got some nice patterns but I was getting into my third page and it seemed never ending. I'm working on uploading the pictures of my scratch work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the first row from the second and third rows, and the new rows will be linearly dependent.

Comment: Wow, what a short cut! Thanks, mate!

Comment: If you know that a determinant is 0, then you're guaranteed linearly dependent rows and columns. Experiment with that idea in mind for these kinds of problems.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why the downvote??

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that the row space is spanned by $(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$ and $(1, 2, , \cdots, n)$, and hence has dimension 2. When $n>2$, the row space is not of full rank so the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
|A|&=\begin{vmatrix}1&2&3&\cdots & n\\
n&n&n&\cdots &n\\
2n&2n&2n&\cdots&2n\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
(n-1)n&(n-1)n&(n-1)n&\cdots&(n-1)n\end{vmatrix}\\
&=n\times 2n\times\cdots\times (n-1)n\begin{vmatrix}1&2&3&\cdots&n\\
1&1&1&\cdots &1\\
1&1&1&\cdots &1\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
1&1&1&\cdots &1\end{vmatrix}\\
&=n^{n-1}(n-1)!\begin{vmatrix}1&2&3&\cdots & n\\
1&1&1&\cdots &1\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}$$

so $rk(A)=2$ and for $n\gt 2$ we have $|A|=0$